# illustrator mask on 2 shapes

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, mask

I am an illustrator newbie. I have 2 shapes: rectangle and triangle. I want to delete the left and the right part of the triangle(just like the image)...Any idea? It s probably easy for you!

[image]

Comment: It would be easiest to just use the Pen tool and draw the top triangle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Select both objects.
- Choose the Shape Builder tool.
- Click in turn on the bottom part of the rounded rectangle, the top part of the rectangle and the top part of the triangle to add them together. (Each area will highlight as you hover over it with the Shape Builder tool, so you can see what you're adding with each click.)
- Deselect.
- Select and delete the bits you don't need.